# Install "File node " in Node-red palette

Tags: file, node-red

I'd like to use "File Node" in Node-Red. I expected to find it in the storage section in the palette but it isn't  in my palette, I try to install using the option Manage Palette in my Node-Red application but I am not able to find/identify the node in the repository .

Could someone telling me how to find the node description to install it in my palette?. Why a don't have it as default?.

[image: Picture of my current node-red palette.]

Comment: I assume you are using Node-RED on the Bluemix platform? The file node does not make sense on a PaaS service as the file system is none persistent and anything stored there that is not part deployed app can be lost at any time when the platform redeploys the app to move it to a new host.

Comment: ...what hardillb said... however, an example of where it is useful is that you have added a file (such as a data file) to your application image and want to load it into the flow.

Comment: I am using Node-red in IBM BLuemix. I am not looking for a persistence of the file.

Comment: As I mentioned storing data to the file system on Bluemix is **REALLY** not a good idea, you may loose that data at any time if the system chooses to move your app to a new host in the cluster. If you need to store data you need to look at one of the Bluemix database options (e.g. cloudant) to ensure the data will not be lost.

Comment: understand , it is for a very small use case for just one day.  I am able to store in cloudant database . After my issue is how to export the data to an spreadsheet  or CSV format

Answer (score 2):

The File nodes are disabled by default in the Bluemix environment to discourage writing files to the volatile storage that will be lost whenever the app is restarted.

You can re-enable it by editing your applications `bluemix-settings.js` file and remove the `file.js` entry in the `nodeExcludes` option.

Comment: Where can I find bleumix-settings.js file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use "node-red-contrib-browser-utils" with the option Manage Palette in Node-Red

Comment: This answer needs a lot more context adding to explain how this node solves the OPs question.